# Homework challenge study, Random generated Strings + Numbers Compare

Tags: java, if-statement, random, java.util.scanner

The concept is create a username 1 and a username 2, assign a string value name1, name2 and then unique integers e.g. 01,02 (Respectively.) 
and then compare the values.

I've written as much code as I understand.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner usernameone = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Username");
        String username1 = usernameone.nextLine();

        int usernameNumber1;
        Scanner usernameNumberOne = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter in your age.");
        usernameNumber1 = usernameNumberOne.nextInt();

        Scanner usernametwo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Username");
        String username2 = usernametwo.nextLine();

        int usernameNumber2;
        Scanner usernameNumberTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter in your age.");
        usernameNumber2 = usernameNumberTwo.nextInt();

        if (username1 <= 0) { // Generate random string for name.
        }
        if (usernameNumber1 <= 0) { // Generate random int for number.     
        }
        if (username2 <= 0) { // Generate random string for name.
        }
        if (usernameNumber2 <= 0) { // Generate random int for number.     
        }
        if (username1 == username2) {
            System.out.println("Username 1 and 2 are same.");
        }
        if (usernameNumber1 == usernameNumber2) {
            System.out.println("Usernumber 1 and 2 are same.");
        }
```

I'm stuck on if the user does not input a number into name 1 or name2 or int 01,02. The program is supposed to randomly generate a number for these variables.

```
//Then I must compare them. 
 //Name 1 == Name 2? 
 //Number 1 == number2? 
 //Name 1 & Number 1 == Name 2 & Number2.
```

Comment: so your program needs 2 string inputs (usernames) and 2 ints for ages? Whats your question? Also you can compare strings only with the equal method (username1.equals(username2))

Comment: First thing: create only one scanner for one input *stream*. Not one scanner for one input. In any case, the problem definition is not clear. What is the required input, what is the required output? What is not working with your code?

Comment: Also note that generating random numbers is extensively documented. At this point, it really looks you want to others do all the relevant parts of your homework...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: @TehMattGR

I thought as much, thankyou, What I was saying was I wasn't sure how to code those above parts the comparison like below using the .equals as you stated as well as random generation.

Comment: alright, you can see my answer below and I added some importand links to check them out. If you have any questions about my code you can ask me or just google it

Comment: @GhostCat, 

Not wanting someone to "Do my homework" It's that I've read many notes and I don't understand, I need help with it that's why I'm here asking, It's actually not a "Homework" question, its an additional study task I've chosen to do to help me learn.

Comment: @TehMattGR Just added a question below wouldn't let me tag you but,

Comment: Stuck with what then exactly? You see, this community isn't a tutor service where people work with you through all aspects of your homework.

Answer (score 0):

**You can learn about the Random Class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and how to compare strings [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java)**

You said that if the user won't enter something, you should generate it.

So, this whole code is wrong:

```
if (username1 <= 0) { // Generate random string for name. // Checking for null strings you check with the null keyword, not 0
}
if (usernameNumber1 <= 0) { // Generate random int for number.
}
if (username2 <= 0) { // Generate random string for name. // and here
}
if (usernameNumber2 <= 0) { // Generate random int for number.
}
if (username1 == username2) { // Wrong String comparing
    System.out.println("Username 1 and 2 are same.");
    }
if (usernameNumber1 == usernameNumber2) {
    System.out.println("Usernumber 1 and 2 are same.");
}
```

What you must do is: Check if the variables are null and if they are generate a random value for them

```
static String genRandomString() { // A helpful method
    Random r = new Random();
    String randomString = "";
    int size = r.nextInt(7) + 3; // 3 is the minimum size and 10 (7 + 3) is the maximum size for the strings
    char[] alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'}; // available characters for the string
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        randomString += alphabet[r.nextInt(alphabet.length - 1)]; // get random char
    }
    return randomString;
}

// after inputs
Random r = new Random();
if (username1.length() == 0) // check if the string's size equals 0
    username1 = genRandomString();
if (username2.length() == 0)
    username2 = genRandomString();
if (usernameNumber1 == 0)
    usernameNumber1 = r.nextInt(50) + 10; // get a random age from 10 to 60
if (usernameNumber2 == 0)
    usernameNumber2 = r.nextInt(50) + 10; // get a random age from 10 to 60
// now check if the usernames are same
if (username1.equals(username2))
    System.out.println("Username 1 and 2 are same.");
// check for ages
if (usernameNumber1 == usernameNumber2)
    System.out.println("Usernumber 1 and 2 are same.");
```

Comment: Thanks TehMattGR, 

I'm getting an error in relation to the method I've now added in the program, I'm assuming it's because I'm using the public static void??. 

https://pastebin.com/uiv0j8vC
(Paste bin link to full code.) 

Also wanted to ask why 
"int size = r.nextInt(7) + 3; // 3 is the minimum size and 10 (7 + 3) is the maximum size for the strings"

Strings can be no larger than 10? I'm pretty new to this all, thankyou for your help.

Comment: make the method static (static String genRandomString()) and r.nextInt(7) + 3 means that we want to take a random int from 0 to 7 and then add to the size 3 (x + 3). 3 is the minimum I selected to be and is outside the parentheses because if the random is 0 we want the size to be at least 3. Sorry for the bad examplanation you can also learn more here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html